# Using React Router DOM Route in Material-UI Breadcrumbs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm trying to dynamically generate a Material-UI Breadcrumb control using the React Router DOM Route component.

Unfortunately, even when the Route component isn't a match and doesn't render anything, it gets added as a child to the breadcrumbs, so I get empty separators in my UI.

Here is my current component.

```
import Breadcrumbs from '@material-ui/core/Breadcrumbs';
import MuiLink from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const MainBreadcrumbs: FC = () => (
    <Breadcrumbs>
        <Route path="/" render={() => (<MuiLink component={Link} to="/">Home</MuiLink>)} />
        <Route path="/jobs" render={() => (<MuiLink component={Link} to="/jobs">Jobs</MuiLink>)} />
        <Route path="/jobs/:jobId" render={route => (<MuiLink component={Link} to={`/jobs/${route.match.params.jobId}`}>Job</MuiLink>)} />
        <Route path="/jobs/:jobId/steps/:stepIndex" render={route => (<MuiLink component={Link} to={`/jobs/${route.match.params.jobId}/${route.match.params.stepIndex}`}>Step</MuiLink>)} />
    </Breadcrumbs>
)

export default MainBreadcrumbs;
```

This results in a component that looks like `Home / / /` when on the homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a possible way to do this using the `useRouteMatch` hook:

```
import React from "react";
import Breadcrumbs from "@material-ui/core/Breadcrumbs";
import { Link, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import MuiLink from "@material-ui/core/Link";

export default function SimpleBreadcrumbs() {
  const homeMatches = useRouteMatch("/");
  const jobsMatches = useRouteMatch("/jobs");
  const jobMatches = useRouteMatch("/jobs/:jobid");
  const stepMatches = useRouteMatch("/jobs/:jobid/:stepIndex");
  return (
    <>
      <Breadcrumbs>
        {homeMatches && (
          <MuiLink component={Link} to="/">
            Home
          </MuiLink>
        )}
        {jobsMatches && (
          <MuiLink component={Link} to="/jobs">
            Jobs
          </MuiLink>
        )}
        {jobMatches && (
          <MuiLink component={Link} to={`/jobs/${jobMatches.params.jobid}`}>
            Job {jobMatches.params.jobid}
          </MuiLink>
        )}
        {stepMatches && (
          <MuiLink
            component={Link}
            to={`/jobs/${jobMatches.params.jobid}/${
              stepMatches.params.stepIndex
            }`}
          >
            Step {stepMatches.params.stepIndex}
          </MuiLink>
        )}
      </Breadcrumbs>
      <Link to="/">Go to Home</Link>
      <br />
      <Link to="/jobs">Go to Jobs</Link>
      <br />
      <Link to="/jobs/123/abc">Go to Job 123, step abc</Link>
      <br />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Breadcrumbs]

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Simple and easier approach. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I did an example for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ys532

EDITED:
So I choose to go with conditional rendering, it may look ugly on the code but you can **abstract** it by making a component BreadCrumbRoute and give all of these as props and it will look as clear as with Route :) 
I started building it check code sandbox, you can finish it by yourself :V---

Comment: Not working when I add more https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ecnf2

Comment: I edited with the full answer :)  feel free to upvote , solution answer :v ----

Comment: Thanks, but that still has issues. It only renders one link and matching path name won't work when I have a dynamic id in the path to match. (e.g. `/jobs/:jobId`)

Comment: check the link again :) I would flirt with startWith (you could add a prop: operator so it knows when = and when startsWith) but there can be many ways, but it would need some good rethinking if you have more than 1 dynamic param

Comment: Yeah, I have multiple dynamic params. I might have to create my own breadcrumb component instead of trying to use the MUI one.

Comment: For multiple dynamics routes, I would have done the same :) FOR OTHERS: you can try to count how many / too and with a smart 3 line algorithm you can have it working without wasting much time :) 
@ToddSkelton maybe accepted solution ? ehehehe some extra reps for all that demo indeed